# how to read upload csv file in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a scaffold (friend) with simple attributes like first_name and last_name and also I'm using the file_field to upload the .csv file which contains 1 column and 5 rows with some integers on it.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: friend, multipart: true) do |form| %>
  <% if friend.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(friend.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this friend from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% friend.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :first_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :last_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :File %>
    <%= form.file_field :File %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>First name:</strong>
  <%= @friend.first_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Last name:</strong>
  <%= @friend.last_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Total:</strong>
  <%= @friend.total %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_friend_path(@friend) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', friends_path %>
```

what i don't understand is where to read the upload csv file and return it's value (after some modification to it) to @friend.total

this is my controller

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_friend, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /friends or /friends.json
  def index
    @friends = Friend.all
  end

  # GET /friends/1 or /friends/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /friends/new
  def new
    @friend = Friend.new
  end

  # GET /friends/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /friends or /friends.json
  def create
    @friend = Friend.new(friend_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @friend.save
        format.html { redirect_to @friend, notice: "Friend was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @friend }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @friend.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /friends/1 or /friends/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @friend.update(friend_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @friend, notice: "Friend was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @friend }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @friend.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /friends/1 or /friends/1.json
  def destroy
    @friend.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to friends_url, notice: "Friend was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_friend
      @friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def friend_params
      params.require(:friend).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :total)
    end
end
```

I'm a newbie at ruby on rails. please let me know if I can describe more about the problem.

Comment: I do know that since we're sending the post request, it must be handled in the create method of the controller

Comment: Can you also show your Friend model please. Genereally Rails will provide the uploaded file as an IO object in `params[:friend][:File]` (you really should NOT use uppercase field names!), and create will put that into the corresponding attribute in your model.
if you have a attachment thing setup like active-storage, carrierwave etc, then the attachment system will take it from there and care about the persistence. if not, you may end up with sth like `<IO .... ` in your database

Comment: you are doing `Friend.find` etc, of course there is a `Friend` model

Comment: `app/models/friend.rb`

Comment: class Friend < ApplicationRecord
end

Comment: if it's empty, then please read up on https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html :) or https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave 
also this question is probably asked hundred times here, look for "Rails file attachment"

Comment: since i'm newbie on rails...can you please provide some resources for learning rails

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/ in general is your friend for almost everything. if you need a tutorial, https://www.railstutorial.org/ is still the best i think. unfortunately it's not free anymore, but it's worth the money

Comment: You're asking multiple different questions here and you really need to break this down and learn one thing at a time. 1. How to deal with file uploads. 2. How to parse a CSV file. 3. How to create multiple records in a single request.  My advice here is to skip this feature for the time being and focus on figuring out the basics and circle back later.

Comment: @MarianTheisen I don't think AS or Carrierwave is actually even relevant here. Its a very vague question without a clear requirement but I doubt he actually wants to attach the file to the model - rather to just process it immediately.